# Why is cudaHostAlloc much slower then cudaMalloc?

Tags: c++, cuda, allocation

I did a simple test with 2 million floats (snippets below). And `cudaMalloc` is about 3x faster then mapped `cudaHostAlloc`. And when I go beyond 2 million, the difference increases, it can be 10-20x faster. Why is this so?

```cpp
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
        cudaEventCreate(&start);
        cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    
        cudaEventRecord(start);
    
        float* data_h;
        cudaHostAlloc((float**)&data_h, sizeof(float) * COUNT, cudaHostAllocMapped);
    
        float* data_h_out;
        cudaHostAlloc((float**)&data_h_out, sizeof(float) * COUNT, cudaHostAllocMapped);
    
        float* data_d;
        cudaHostGetDevicePointer((float**)&data_d, (float*)data_h, 0);
    
        float* data_d_out;
        cudaHostGetDevicePointer((float**)&data_d_out, (float*)data_h_out, 0);
    
        cudaEventRecord(stop);
        cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    
        float milliseconds = 0;
        cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);
        printf("milliseconds allocate = %f\n", milliseconds);
```

vs

```cpp
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);

    cudaEventRecord(start);

    float* data_d;
    cudaMalloc(&data_d, sizeof(float) * COUNT);

    float* data_d_out;
    cudaMalloc(&data_d_out, sizeof(float) * COUNT);

    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);

    float milliseconds = 0;
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&milliseconds, start, stop);

    printf("milliseconds allocate = %f\n", milliseconds);
```

Comment: cudaHostAlloc is page locking CPU ram. Depending on how much paging is required that can be painfully slow. Why do you imagine that there should be performance parity between the two operations?

Comment: @talonmies thank you for your quick answer. Do you happen to know, how to boost cudaHostAlloc performance, or it is what it is?

Comment: It is what it is. Reuse allocations and limit the total size to something reasonable. That's all you can do.

Comment: Maybe you can write and answer and I will check it. This might help other in future.

Comment: While page locking is slow, I do not understand why it would be so slow assuming the OS use transparent huge page. Maybe this is the root of the problem : are huge page used in this case and can huge pages be (directly) locked on the target OS?